# Multiple processes spawned when running Django runserver

Tags: django, performance, memory, process

Sometimes, When I run Django (**ver 4.1.6**) runserver and monitor the usage memory usage using htop I see that there multiple processes or threads spawned (see the below image).

[image]

The same thing doesn't happen when running another application's Django even though most of the code is almost identical.

Any idea why this is happening? Is there any setting to determine the number of threads? and how do I figure out where the issue is?